# Добавление пробелов к строке

Tags: python

Все здравствуйте.
Есть код. Он выводит номер максимальной строки. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы к строкам, длинна которых не максимальная добавить такое колличество пробелов в начало строк, чтобы все строки были одной длинны?

```
n = 5
a = []
for i in range(n):
    print(i+1,end='-я: ')
    a.append(input())
index = 0
for i in range(1, n):
    if len(a[i]) > len(a[index]):
        index = i

for i in range(n):
    if len(a[i]) == len(a[index]):
        print(i + 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Ещё один вариант, самый лёгкий в исполнении. У str есть метод rjust и ljust, которые добавляют указанный символ слева или справа, пока длина строки не будет равна указанной:

```py
>>> a = "Hello, World!"

>>> print(a.rjust(15, " "));
"  Hello, World!"
```

Answer (score 1):

Допустим, у вас есть количество символов в строке максимальной длины `n` и строка для обработки `s`:

```
s = ' '*(n - len(s)) + s
```

```
>>> def func(n, s):
    return {'return':' '*(n-len(s))+s, 's_len':len(s), 'new len':len(' '*(n-len(s))+s), 'desired_len':n}

>>> func(15, 'fdsf')
{'return': '           fdsf', 's_len': 4, 'new len': 15, 'desired_len': 15}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
max = 10
a = [...]
while len(a) != max:
   a.insert(0, ' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
max_len = 10

value = 123

print(f'{value:>{max_len}}')
```